# Call a cocoa/obj-c method from a C++ dylib in MAC OS X

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, cocoa

Since I am fairly new to Objective-C programming language, I'm facing a huge problem: how can I call a method of my application (made in Objective-C) from my dynamically loaded library (made in C++), by passing it some parameters?

I've been digging the web for a couple of days with no luck. The only thing I found is about IMP, but I'm not sure if that's what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have a plethora of options here.

1. If the dylib is one of your own, you can compile it as Objective-C++ for Mac OS X and `#ifdef` the objective-C calls (or not if you are only targeting Mac OS)
2. Both Obj-C and C++ can make use of C interfaces, so you could write an adapter layer in C (remember Obj-c is a strict superset of C) and expose it for the dylib to call the C functions which then call the Obj-C code.
3. You can use [Blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)), which work in C, C++, and of course Obj-C
4. you can include the objective-c runtime (see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)) and muck with that (This is where you would use the `*IMP` thing you mentioned).
5. Yet another option might be to use Objective C++ from the Cocoa side to setup C++ objects and expose those to the dylib. How you would go about this really depends on what the library is and how it is used etc; we need to know more about the dylib and how it is being used to elaborate on this.

Since you specifically mention using an `IMP` lets talk a bit more in depth about that. The declaration is `typedef void (*IMP)(id self, SEL _cmd, ...);` which you can see takes a pointer to an Obj-C objects, and a `SEL` (selector), which is just a special C-String representation of the method. You can read more about both `SEL` and `IMP` in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html).

You can also make use of the runtime's C functions such as `objc_msgSend` to call a method by passing a pointer to the object and a `SEL` just like with `IMP`.

This should be enough information to get you started. Thanks for this question BTW, I never really sat down and thought about all the possible ways to combine C++ with Objective-C before. Odds are I even missed something ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i'm investigating IMP and the call to objc_msgSend in my C++ dylib. With my library I just need a basic thing for the moment: to call an Objective-C method from a method inside the dylib.

Answer (score 0):

You can use objective c runtime

```
include <objc/runtime.h>

objc_msgSend(id, SEL, arg0, ...)
```

where
id - is the object where you want to send message
SEL - is struct pointer, describing message you send.
arg0,... are the arguments that you pass to selector.

For more understanding of runtime, see the source code http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/

Also you can cast IMP address, and call the function.

```
int(* foo)(id, SEL, arg) = IMP;
foo(someObject, @selector(someMessage), arg);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to figure out how to call objc_msgsend from my dylib c++ code (i.e. how is the proper way to call it from there, etc)