# Golang, CGO, double pointers and macos Foundation framework

Tags: c, objective-c, go, foundation, cgo

First, I have some basic C experience, but not too fluent with CGO and macos programming

I write a function, that removes a file in a system Trash. I have a working code, that I try to improve

The code first:

```golang
package trash

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -x objective-c
#cgo LDFLAGS: -framework Foundation
#import "trash.h"
*/
import "C"
import (
    "errors"
    "unsafe"
)

// TrashItem puts items into system trash
func TrashItem(filePath string) error {
    cString := C.CString(filePath)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cString))

    var cErr = new(C.Error)

    res := C.TrashItem(cString, cErr)
    if res == 0 {
        // convert cErr to go error
        return errors.New("...")
    }

    return nil
}
```

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef struct _Error {
    long C;
    const char *E;
} Error;

const BOOL TrashItem(const char *filePath, Error *error);
```

(I googled a lot to write this code, not sure, how good it is)

```c
#import "trash.h"

const BOOL TrashItem(const char *filePath, Error *error) {
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:@(filePath)];

    NSError *e;
    BOOL success = [manager trashItemAtURL:fileURL resultingItemURL:nil error:&e];
    if (!success) {
        error->C = e.code;
        error->E = [e.localizedDescription UTF8String];
    }

    return success;
}
```

First issue:

I don't wont to always initialize `var cErr = new(C.Error)`. I think I could make trash function accept `Error **error`, but I struggle to pass double pointer from go to C (I have `go pointer have go pointer` error)

Second issue:

I would like to avoid custom `Error` struct and pass `NSError *` and access fields from go side.

I had `Incompatible pointer types passing 'struct NSError *' to parameter of type 'NSError *`, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/60715306/889530 solved it for me

But I think I still need `NSError **`, so I can read the data back, and again I struggle with `void` and double pointers here.

Can somebody explain me how to do that properly

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're after. Re 1st issue: please state what's your end goal? Not having to allocate the error object on the Go side and pass it from TrashItem instead? If yes, just do it: make TrashItem accept a pointer to pointer (there's no such thing as "double"  (or "triple" etc) pointers), allocate an object in that function and write a pointer to it via the pointer submitted to the call. The caller will still have to do something like `var cErr C.Error` and call `C.TrashItem(fileName, &cErr)`. Note that the caller will be required to call `C.free` on the returned error.

Comment: Re 2nd issue—I fail to quite parse what the problem is.I mean, it would be better to ask a separate, as much narrow as possible, question with an [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean): that is, your attempted solution (which does not work), relevant (compiler) error messages and the desired outcome. Note that for an MCVE, nothing is relevant except for the way you want to deal with `NSError` and pointers to it. So a minimal function which does just that would be ideal.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is not C but rather Objective-C ("objectionable-C" as some call it). Apple have taken some pains to make sure you can use one from the other to some extent, but it's always a bit dicey to make use of objc from C code as there's a whole objc runtime system. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26018621/1256452).

Comment: A correction to my 1st comment—I actually meant using something like `var cErrPtr *C.Error` and `C.TrashItem(fileName, &cErrPtr)`, supposing that the latter writes a pointer to an `Error` it allocates itself via the pointer passed to the call. The client is then obviously required to `C.free` that object as it now "owns" it. Sorry for the confusion. One more thing: you don't actually have to call `new` in your existing code: you could just declare `var cErr C.Error` and pass a pointer to it to the function as written now. Maybe that's all you need to be fine with this solution?